# Windows tool to check for used files (by Java OSGi process)

Tags: java, windows, file, osgi, jprofiler

I'm looking for a tool that'll give me information about file operations (e.g. open/close/read/write, how many bytes, how many time waited), filtered by process and that'll allow me to have a file with this information incremented for a few hours.

Right now I'm using Process Monitor but the information that they show it's just for the moment, doesn't save it to later use. The application to profile it's a OSGi server, I've tried to do it with JProfiler but gives me "This probe it's not available in attach mode", don't know why.

Comment: "This probe it's not available in attach mode" -> Don't use the quick attach feature. Either use an IDE integration to start the profiled JVM or use the integration wizard via Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration to get the VM parameter that loads the profiling agent.

Answer (score 1):

if your app runs on Windows (x86 or x64), try my tool, D Probe which has build-in file system filter, you can examine, query, filter, save the captured records,  my profile page has a download link, btw, it's free.

Comment: I'll give it a try on monday, thanks for the tip and for the hard word that you are willing to share :)

Comment: I fixed a crash bug of my tool, if you downloaded old version, please update with the latest version.